# Odd segfault occuring on EOF exit of fgetc while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, malloc, fgetc

So I've combed through this thing pretty thoroughly using printf statements (on mobile) and have narrowed the location of the error down to the nested if (ret == EOF) statement in the read_file function. The data is successfully copied but segfaults on exit of the function. Any chance someone might be able to take a look for me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_BYTES 1024

typedef int8_t byte;

typedef struct file_buffer {
    
    char * file_name;
    void * raw_data;
    
    uint64_t file_size;
    uint64_t max_size;
    uint64_t temps_copied;
    uint16_t bytes_in_temp;
    uint8_t filled;
    
    FILE * fp;
    
} FB;



void * open_file(const char * file_name);

static FB * new_buffer(const char * file_name);

static void read_file(FB * fb, FILE * fp);

static void copy_buffer(FB * fb, byte * temp, const int size);

static void check_size(FB * fb, const int size);



int main()
{
    open_file("./src/MOCK_DATA.csv");
    return 0;
}


void * open_file(const char * file_name)
{
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    //
    
    FB * buffer = new_buffer(file_name);
    
    read_file(buffer, fp);
    
    return buffer->raw_data;
}




static FB * new_buffer(const char * file_name)
{
    FB * fb = calloc(1, sizeof(FB));
    //
    
    fb->raw_data = calloc(MAX_BYTES, sizeof(byte));
    //
    
    size_t name_size = strlen(file_name) + 1;
    fb->file_name = malloc(sizeof(char) * name_size);
    //
    memcpy(fb->file_name, file_name,  name_size);
    
    return fb;
}



static void read_file(FB * fb, FILE * fp)
{
    byte temp[MAX_BYTES];
    byte nb = 0;
   
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int ret;
 
    while (ret = (nb = (fgetc(fp))))
    {
     if ((ret == EOF) || (j == (MAX_BYTES - 1)))
        {
            if (ret == EOF) {
                copy_buffer(fb, &temp[0], i);                
                return;
        }
        
        else {
            copy_buffer(fb, &temp[0], i);
            
            fb->bytes_in_temp = 0;
            j = 0;
            i = i + 1;
        }
        }
        fb->bytes_in_temp);
        
        temp[j] = nb;
        
        fb->bytes_in_temp++;
        j = j + 1;
    }
}



static void copy_buffer(FB * fb, byte * temp, const int size)
{
    check_size(fb, size);
    
    int start = MAX_BYTES * size;
    
    memcpy(&fb->raw_data[start], temp, fb->bytes_in_temp);
}



static void check_size(FB * fb, const int size)
{
    if (fb->temps_copied < size)
    {
        void * temp = realloc(fb->raw_data, (MAX_BYTES + fb->max_size) * sizeof(byte));
        
        fb->raw_data = temp;        
        fb->temps_copied = size;
        fb->max_size += MAX_BYTES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing `#include <stdint.h>`, implement error check `fopen()`, `fb->bytes_in_temp)` is a syntax error (and does nothing if the `)` is removed), ` memcpy(&fb->raw_data[start], temp, fb->bytes_in_temp);` dereferences a void pointer.  You rely on a particular file we don't have so can't test this for you.  Run it in a debugger, if that doesn't enlight valgrind to find heap corruption.

Comment: Why do you open a .csv file in "rb" opposed to "r" mode?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue (after adding a file and/or implementing fopen error checking).  Might depend on size of .csv.

Comment: `open_file()`a return a `void *raw_data` but caller cannot tell how much data is being returned.

Comment: Ahhh, so if I just malloc a bunch of space and return it to the calling function it has no idea how large the space it points to is?

Comment: Well yeah. Why else did you not check if there was enough space to raw_data to accommodate the memcpy.

Comment: Duuuuuuuuuuh. Thank you. That seems so obvious.